# Optimizing Heroku, Rails, and Unicorn: defining proper configuration options like how many worker processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, mongoid, unicorn

We have the following configuration file for Unicorn. We're on Rails 3.2.12 and Mongoid 3.1.16. How should we determine how many worker processes to use? Are there other options we could include to boost performance?

Thanks!

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 25
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # TERM signals indicates the Heroku Dyno is shutting down
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # TERM signals indicates the Heroku Dyno is shutting down
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two resources you need to run a Rails unicorn worker process: memory and CPU.

Most likely, you will run out of memory before you are able to exhaust the CPU resources on a Heroku dyno.  Therefore, measure the loaded in-memory size of your app per unicorn worker and you get a rough number of workers you can fit with some headroom.

For example, if your app need about 110mb (common Rails 3.2 needs), you can fit about 4 on a single 1X dyno.

Heroku provides 2X dynos with more memory and CPU.  I do not recommend 2X dynos because they have not delivered 2x performance in our benchmarks.

You can spin up a terminal on a dyno to manually run unicorn and measure the memory usage via:

```
> heroku run bash
> unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb & # Run unicorn in the background
> ps euf # Read RSS value for each worker, in kb - ie: 116040 ~ 116mb
```

You can view your Application configuration using:

```
> heroku config
> heroku config | grep WEB_CONCURRENCY # Filter config output to WEB_CONCURRENCY
```

EDIT:
[Heroku posted updated information about dyno sizing three months after I originally answered this.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-size)

Comment: cool, thanks! how do you recommend we measure the in-memory size of each app per unicorn worker?

Comment: also how do we see the value of ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"]? (someone else configured this file for us.) thanks!

Comment: Updated to add these two things.

Comment: thanks! and if we want to view the value of a ENV var directly, is there another way to do it? similar to the echo command but for heroku.

Comment: Each dyno is a virtual machine. Unless you are running an interactive bash dyno you should use heroku config. In the rare case you're debugging an interactive dyno, you can look at the environment using echo or env.

Comment: Part of this is incorrect. Heroku 2X dynos give you twice the memory and twice the CPU. See the heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-size#available-dyno-sizes

Comment: @Winfeld could you update this to reflect the fact that 2X dynos give 2X CPU power

Answer (score 10):

This currently accepted answer has some incorrect information in it.

According to the [heroku docs on dyno size](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-size#available-dyno-sizes), 2X dynos have a 2X cpu share, not *just* double the memory:

[image]

Regardless, since the number of unicorn workers that can be used is bound to memory footprint, you'll most likely get more performance out of a 2X dyno where you can better use the available memory.

For example, you might be able to run one 2X dyno with 7 unicorn workers vs. two 1X dynos with 3 unicorn workers (6 total). There is also likely some routing overhead when using more dynos.

Via the [heroku docs on optimizing dyno usage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/optimizing-dyno-usage#ruby):

> While highly app dependent, the following table lists some rough rules of thumb for how many Unicorn workers can be run on each dyno size:

[image]

With that in mind, the most important thing to know for optimizing usage is total memory footprint. You can enable heroku's [log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics) to have **actual** memory and cpu usage information printed to the heroku logs. It'll look something like this:

```
source=web.1 dyno=heroku.2808254.d97d0ea7-cf3d-411b-b453-d2943a50b456 sample#load_avg_1m=2.46 sample#load_avg_5m=1.06 sample#load_avg_15m=0.99
source=web.1 dyno=heroku.2808254.d97d0ea7-cf3d-411b-b453-d2943a50b456 sample#memory_total=21.00MB sample#memory_rss=21.22MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=348836pages sample#memory_pgpgout=343403pages
```

As mentioned in the above linked article, you can use that in conjunction with the [librato add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/librato#nickel) to graph usage over time to get a better sense of your app's peak usage requirements:

[image]

The [NewRelic add on](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic) can be used for a similar purpose.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

*How should we determine how many worker processes to use?*

The "best" way I've determined this is just by slowly increasing the number of workers until the dynos start to warn you about memory issues via the log files.  From what I've found for a pretty general rails app receiving moderate traffic, a 1x dyno can safely handle 3 unicorn workers and a 2x dyno can safely handle 7 unicorn workers.  I was able to bump this to 4 and 8 respectively, but within a day or so, I began to get memory errors and workers regularly restarting themselves.

Yes, this method of determining how many worker processes is extremely brute force, but even [Heroku's Unicorn docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn#caveats) say "between 2-4 workers"...

*Are there other options we could include to boost performance?*

For Unicorn?  Probably not, outside of tweaking your workers...

Other than Unicorn, there are a couple relatively easy solutions to add and integrate with a Heroku Rails app:

1. Cache, cache, cache.  Heroku has a bunch of middleware add-ons for caching.  I'd recommend  checking out [memcache](https://addons.heroku.com/memcachedcloud) and/or [redis](https://addons.heroku.com/rediscloud) - both have Heroku plans which are free to try out, and really quick to hook up to your app.
2. I'd also look to see if there are any processes which can be run by background workers using either [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).  You'll need to spin up a background worker on Heroku and [configure your application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque) to use background workers - which will cost you another dyno as far as money spent, but if you have long-processing features in your app, the performance boost to the consumer-facing portion can be extremely significant.